# Can't execute `netplan apply` command in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: netplan

The command `netplan apply` returns some errors when I execute it as root user.

```
root@szyf1272:/etc/netplan# netplan apply

System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/netplan", line 23, in <module>
    netplan.main()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/core.py", line 50, in main
    self.run_command()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 186, in run_command
    self.func()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 46, in run
    self.run_command()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 186, in run_command
    self.func()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 116, in command_apply
    utils.systemctl_networkd('stop', sync=sync, extra_services=wpa_services)
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 86, in systemctl_networkd
    subprocess.check_call(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['systemctl', 'stop', '--no-block', 'systemd-networkd.service', 'netplan-wpa-*.service']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Did you try `netplan try` first?

Comment: If you're doing this from WSL, then then it is using init.d instead systemd. You won't be able to run netplan directly.

Answer (score 0):

This error is returned from systemd in response to the command:

`systemctl stop --no-block systemd-networkd.service 'netplan-wpa-*.service'`

This checks whether `/run/systemd/system` exists and is accessible.

This is always true on a correctly booted Ubuntu 20.04 system.

I don't know what you might have done to cause this directory to be absent, but such a system is badly broken and unsupportable.